# How can i remove those \n in python?

Tags: python

So only useful part of code is

```
print(gender)
print(age)
print(height)
print(health[randomm])
print(hobby[randomm])
print(phobia[randomm])
print(character[randomm])
print(inventory[randomm])
print(additionalInformation[randomm])
print(cardN1[randomm])
print(cardN2[randomm])
```

The output is

```
2
103
199
Ишемическая болезнь сердца

Благотворительность

Авиафобия

Доброта

Набор инструментов

В 1998 году выпил первую бутылку пива.

Поменятся с одним человеком болезнью 1 раз.

Поменяться случайному человеку болезнь.
```

I copied it right from console and my main question is how i can removes those empty lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.replace()`

```
string = "Hello \n World"
print(string.replace("\n", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that `print` adds a newline when printing a string. When printing `"test\n"`, you end up with `"test\n\n"`, which creates blanks.

```
>>> print("test\n")
test
```

You have multiple options here. You can remove the `\n` from the string:

```
>>> print("test\n".strip())
test
```

Or remove the automatic newline from `print`:

```
>>> print("test\n", end='')
test
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write separate print function for each line. just write all the lines in a single print function with \n in between those statements.

```
print(health[randomm]\nhobby[randomm])
```